# Any Solana-Ethereum NFT Bridge example? Or can someone explain how I can achieve this?

Tags: solana-program, nft, ethereum, burn

I wanted to know how Solana-Ethereum NFT bridge works, So please refer me to a relevant guide or explain how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking out the docs for WormHole as they have a bridge for transferring NFT.Here is the [link](https://book.wormhole.com/) and i assume this [frontend](https://www.portalbridge.com/#/nft) allow's to transfer NFT from Solana to other EVM based chains so check it out.